# LinkedIn Campagin API Link not inserted

Tags: php, curl, linkedin-api

I am using the marketing API to create ads with curl in PHP.
Creating Campaign Groups and Campaigns in this way is working perfectly fine. The basic creation of a creative and an ad is also working. The only problem is that I can’t add a destination URL and some other info’s like the description and Call-to-Action. But the destination URL or content Landing Page like it’s called in the documentation really is fundamental.

This is my code for the creative data:

```
$data = [
    "creative" => [
        "inlineContent" => [
            "post" => [
                "adContext" => [
                    "dscAdAccount" => "urn:li:sponsoredAccount:".$this->params->get('app.linkedin_my_acc_id'),
                    "dscStatus" => "ACTIVE"
                ],
                "author" => "urn:li:organization:".$this->params->get('app.linkedin_my_org_id'),
                "commentary" => $job->getCommentary(),
                "visibility" => "PUBLIC",
                "lifecycleState" => "PUBLISHED",
                "isReshareDisabledByAuthor" => false,
                "contentCallToActionLabel" => "DOWNLOAD",
                "contentLandingPage" => "https://google.com",
                "content" => [
                    "media" => [
                        "title" => "This is a test!",
                        "id" => $image
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ],
        "campaign" => "urn:li:sponsoredCampaign:".$myCampaignId,
        "intendedStatus" => "ACTIVE"
    ]
];
```

The structure is the same as in the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads/account-structure/create-and-manage-creatives-new?view=li-lms-2023-01&tabs=http#creatives-inline-schema).
So what am I doing wrong? Why is LinkedIn ignoring my `contentLandingPage` and `contentCallToActionLabel` values? The request is working and I'm not getting an unpermitted fields error so it seems to be correct…
Can someone help? I also can provide the code of the Campaign Group and the Campaign if needed.

Not sure if this is important but the objectiveType of my Campaign is “WEBSITE_VISIT” and the type is “SPONSORED_UPDATES”.

Answer (score 2):

After discussion with the Linkedin support, I've managed to solve the problem by replacing `media` in the `content` with `article`.

In your case, you would simply need to send these data instead :

```js
$data = [
    "creative" => [
        "inlineContent" => [
            "post" => [
                "adContext" => [
                    "dscAdAccount" => "urn:li:sponsoredAccount:".$this->params->get('app.linkedin_my_acc_id'),
                    "dscStatus" => "ACTIVE"
                ],
                "author" => "urn:li:organization:".$this->params->get('app.linkedin_my_org_id'),
                "commentary" => $job->getCommentary(),
                "visibility" => "PUBLIC",
                "lifecycleState" => "PUBLISHED",
                "isReshareDisabledByAuthor" => false,
                "contentCallToActionLabel" => "DOWNLOAD",
                "contentLandingPage" => $displayed_url,
                "content" => [
                    "article" => [
                        "source" => $destination_url,
                        "thumbnail" => $image,
                        "title" => "This is a test!",
                        "description" => "Your description"
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ],
        "campaign" => "urn:li:sponsoredCampaign:".$myCampaignId,
        "intendedStatus" => "ACTIVE"
    ]
];
```